# Finding one embedded document in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, embed

So I have these 2 schemas and it won't let me have **one object only** but it **returns the whole array of objects instead**

```
const ReqEmbSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    appId: String,
    lname: String,
    fname: String,
    midname: String
});



const RequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    appId: String,
    userRequest: [ReqEmbSchema]
});
```

I tried doing this to get 1 specific embedded object from ReqEmbSchema

```
 const update = "zDfXUoQhc8";
Request.findOne({'userRequest.appId': update}, function(err,foundRequest){
            console.log(foundRequest);
        });
```

But sadly it returns all embedded objects in my log. Please help me fix .

Comment: set projection in second parameter `.findOne({'userRequest.appId': update}, { "userRequest.$":1 }, your callback)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Almost, it only returns  this ` [ { userRequest: [ [Object] ] } ] ` I want to get the values of of that embedded object